# KSH Shell Double Variable names?

Tags: shell, variables, set, ksh, typeset

I am trying to create a variable based on $i

```
i=1
line="one two three four five six"

while [[ $i -lt 3 ]]; do 
set string$i=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f1-3`
echo $string$i
do_stuff_here
done
```

when i do this I get the following output

```
1
```

the expected output is

```
one two three
```

In Fact when I echo $String1...i get the expected output...so its stored correctly.
I know its the way I am calling $string$1...but I have tried all kinds of quotes/parenthesis and Its not working. Can someone tell me how to call my variable?

Comment: Is `$string$1` a typo for `$string$i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop never stops unless you increment i in do_stuff_there, anyway, this should be closer to what you are expecting:

```
i=1
line="one two three four five six"

while [[ $i -lt 3 ]]; do
  eval string$i=\"`echo $line | cut -d" " -f1-3`\"
  eval echo \$string$i
  do_stuff_here
done
```